# Kali Linux (Debian) can't install pip.py

Tags: python, linux, debian, pip

I am trying to install 'python-pip', on kali linux (debian derived distribution), using the command below:

```
    apt-get install python-pip
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I am getting above error.

Any help?

Comment: [python-pip](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-pip) is a valid package name, so what you've typed should work - check your `sources.list` to make sure that you're getting packages from the right place and run `apt-get update` to see if that helps. This really belongs on [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: Newbee here, how to check sources.list? @GoBusto

Comment: You can find it in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and can view/edit it with any text editor. See the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) for more information. Also, this may be obvious, but are you running `apt-get` as root?

Comment: It has only one source & that is
 ## Security updates
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
I don't believe its the correct one! @GoBusto

Comment: You'll need more lines than just that - that repository would only contain security updates.

Answer (score 5):

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

install this as a 'py' file. Go to Linux terminal type in

```
root# python get-pip.py
```

Assuming downloaded file is located in 'root'

Answer (score 2):

u/jelmer is correct, your /etc/apt/sources.list needs two more lines. Open the sources file and add these two lines

```
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

afterwards open your terminal run

```
apt-get update
```

Pip should install easily with

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

See http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories for details.